# Undefined variable when connecting to a database

Tags: php, oop, constructor

I don't know why `user`, `host` and `password` variables are undefined when I try to call the `connect()` method

```
    $app->get('/get', function () use($app){
        $db = new Db_handler;
        $db->connect();
    }
);
```

And here is the `Db_handler` class itself

```
    <?php
        class Db_handler{
                private $driver;
                private $host;
                private $port;
                private $schema;
                private $username;
                private $password;

                function Db_handler( $config_file = 'connection.ini' ){
                        if(!$connection_data = parse_ini_file($config_file, true)) throw new exception("No se puedo abrr el fichero de configuracion ".$config_file." .");
                        $driver = $connection_data["database"]["driver"];
                        $host = $connection_data["database"]["host"];
                        $port = $connection_data["database"]["port"];
                        $schema = $connection_data["database"]["schema"];
                        $username = $connection_data["database"]["username"];
                        $password = $connection_data["database"]["password"];

                        echo $host;
                        echo $username;
                        echo $password;
                }

                function connect(){
                        $link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $root)
                        or die('No se pudo conectar: ' . mysql_error());
                }

        }
?>
```

The echo of the constructor shows the variables correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor and in the `connect()` method, use $this to preface each var name.

```
$this->driver = ...
$this->host   = ...
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your connect function. Change this line:

```
$link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $root)
```

to this:

```
$link = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password)
```

Variables used in function connect are local variables which are not initialized. When you use keyword $this with pointer -> you will call class variables which are already defined in constructor. So as well it's important to set class private variables inside constructor:

```
$this->driver = $connection_data["database"]["driver"];
$this->host = $connection_data["database"]["host"];
$this->port = $connection_data["database"]["port"];
$this->schema = $connection_data["database"]["schema"];
$this->username = $connection_data["database"]["username"];
$this->password = $connection_data["database"]["password"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the undifined variable is only $root. 
You call `mysql_connect($host, $username, $root)` 
and $root is not declared anywhere.